# Android version 4.3 and higher backround picture is not displaying

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I use Android Studio 2.0. I put background picture to background 4.3 and higher versions are not displaying picture. Only white background. But less versions display background picture. Background picture is placed at drawable folder. Picture is `1280х1768 png`. How to make to display background picture at all versions of Android? Where is my mistake? Please give me your advices. Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

**Here is xml of layout activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Мундарижа"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_pressed_selector"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55px" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Китоб ҳақида"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_pressed_selector"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55px" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Муаллиф ҳақида"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_pressed_selector"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55px" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Чиқиш маълумоти"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_pressed_selector"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0" 
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55px" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/olti"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think this is because of high resolution image reduce image size to 420x800 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use This **ImageButton**:

passing fixed height,width and applying scaleType should work.

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imgButton5"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/olti"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the image in all the drawable folders - hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi and then add it to your android:background and keep your scaleType to fitXY. It should work !

Comment: And Change the image button to image and set onclick for the image